# night day circuit voltage drop

Tags: transistors, reverse-polarity

I found this circuit on internet looking for a "ON when dark/OFF when light" circuit:

[image: night-day circuit]

When I mounted it, it worked as expected, the only problem is that voltage between A and B is 8.71v instead of 12v.

What can I do to get the 12v between A and B?

Comment: So the diode you show is not a diode but a module rated for 12V?  If so you don't need R3.

Comment: Data sheet for the LED wouldhelp.

Comment: You are right John, I'm not using R3. In the place of the diode is an electric fence energizer that works with 12v and 60ma. It works with the 8.7v also, but slower, spark every 4 secs instead of every sec.

Comment: In that case seems like you need more base current in T2.  You could try increasing the value of R2 to maybe 4.7K or so. Though there should be a resistor in series with the base for current limiting.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The cause was a mixture of lack of sleep and mere noob stupidity. I interpreted the long bar of the battery source as negative, the polarity was reversed.
Thanks for taking the time to answer and apologies.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, **[accept the answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)** that you found most helpful.  - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/149871)

Comment: Hi Enric. The "thank you" goes after the answer. I can't accept my answer till tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

You will never be able to get a pure 12V with that power supply, as there will be some voltage drop across the transistor. The easist way would be to increase your supply voltage. You can do that with a simple boost converter or add another battery in series.

Comment: It's hard to tell which transistor T2 is due to the scrawl on the schematic, but the saturation voltage should be around 0.5V or less, so 11.5V isn't unrealistic.  8.7V means the transistor is not being driven hard enough or the load current is much higher than the transistor is rated for.

Comment: Good point. Yes. The transistor definately needs to driven harder however there will always be a voltage drop.

Answer (score 0):

Since T2 will switch a load on and off, it should be driven into saturation. Under saturation, the voltage across its collector and emitter will be less than 1V *(depending on the load current)*. But seems like T2 is not driven into saturation, because the voltage drops it is around 3.5V.

One practical way to drive a transistor into saturation is forcing its base current to be one tenth of its collector current (Even one twentieth would be sufficient but one tenth is a well guaranteed ratio). So, with this assumption, a base current of 5-6mA for T2 is enough. The current through R2 will be \$V_{BE}/220R=3mA\$, so the collector current of T1 should be around 10mA.

Assuming \$\beta=100\$ for BD140 *(datasheet says that it can be any value between 25 and 250)*, the base current of T1 should be 0.1mA. So the LDR's resistance plus pot value should be low enough to allow this amount of base current.

One practical solution is to use a MOSFET in place of T2.